# Cannot resolve method setText/getText

Tags: java, android

So I am still learning Android and Java and I was trying to follow the code on this page: http://www.androidauthority.com/use-remote-web-api-within-android-app-617869/

The thing is that the code they provide does not work for me, and Android Studio says Cannot resolve method for both the setText and the getText methods.

This is my code:

```
    package com.example.beldr.apitest;

    import android.os.AsyncTask;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.ProgressBar;
    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;
    import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
    import java.net.URL;
    import static com.example.beldr.apitest.R.id.emailText;
    import static com.example.beldr.apitest.R.id.responseView;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
    }

    class RetrieveFeedTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {


    private Exception exception;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;

    protected void onPreExecute() {


        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        responseView.setText("");
    }

    protected String doInBackground(Void... urls) {
        String email = emailText.getText().toString();
        // Do some validation here

        try {
            URL url = new URL("https://api.fullcontact.com/v2/person.json" + "email=" + email + "&apiKey=" + "126042055");
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            try {
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                String line;
                while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    stringBuilder.append(line).append("\n");
                }
                bufferedReader.close();
                return stringBuilder.toString();
            }
            finally{
                urlConnection.disconnect();
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            Log.e("ERROR", e.getMessage(), e);
            return null;
        }
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String response) {
        if(response == null) {
            response = "THERE WAS AN ERROR";
        }
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        Log.i("INFO", response);
        responseView.setText(response);
    }
}
```

And this is the activity_main.xml

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.beldr.apitest.MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="368dp"
        android:layout_height="495dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context="com.sample.foo.simplewebapi.MainActivity"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp">
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/emailText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:hint="Enter email address"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/queryButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
            android:text="Search"/>
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center">
            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/progressBar"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:indeterminate="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:visibility="gone" />
            <ScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/responseView"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            </ScrollView>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

EDIT: I tried putting

```
TextView textView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.responseView);
```

But then it says Cannot resolve method to the findViewById

Comment: You need to call `findViewById()` method. ((View) findViewById(responseView)).setText("");

Comment: responseView is an id, you need an object from that id

Comment: I suggest that you use better educational resources than random blog posts with incomplete code, so that you do not need to guess how to complete that code.

Comment: `R.id.responseView` is a `long` identifier. It is not the component you need. Use `findViewById()` methiod to get the actual component.

Answer (score 0):

```
TextView responseView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.responseView);
```

then you'll be able to `.setText()` ect

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using those methods from ids and not from objects.

This should be the way:

```
EditText etEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.emailText);
TextView tvResponse = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.responseView);
```

Then you can call getText() and setText() from etEmail and tvResponse.

Bonus: remove these lines

```
import static com.example.beldr.apitest.R.id.emailText;
    import static com.example.beldr.apitest.R.id.responseView;
```

and just use:

```
import com.example.beldr.apitest.R
```

Comment: Also I have tried your bonus and it does not work. It marks it as never used and when I try to use it says cannot resolve symbol.

Comment: Weird... If you create an Android project from scratch you will notice that it is the same way as I have written it. Maybe you can try to compile the project first.

Comment: But I can't compile the project with errors still in it, or I am missing something?

Comment: Sometimes happens that you need to compile the project in order to generate those values inside R. At least talking from my experience. In such cases I comment the code I need to compile the project and then uncomment it and see if values inside R were generated. Did you try to generate a new project from AS and see how it looks like?

Comment: Tried commenting code that gave error and compiled. Still error after compiling and uncommenting. Will try to generate a new project tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

Put

```
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.responseView);
```

into onCreate() method and make variable **TextView textView** global in class, so then you can call it from AsyncTask

Comment: I tried it, but then it says cannot resolve methon on the setText